# Is it possible to have a generic element in a CSS selector?

Tags: html, css

For instance, let's say that I want every element under an `h1` of class `title` to have a `margin-top` of `30px`, because sometimes the element under it is an `h2`, other times it's a `p`, other times an element with a class of `my-class`, etc. Is there something that would be equivalent to

```
h1.title + h2, 
h1.title + p, 
h1.title + .my-class,
.... [Any other possible element under h1.title !!!]
{
...
}
```

Comment: Why not just give the `h1` a margin-bottom?

Comment: 'Under' meaning vertically below the `<h1>` on screen, or meaning a child of the `<h1>` element?

Comment: Even if you can use the `*` selector as commented it can be much for just give a margin ... I will go with @Paulie_D suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `h1.title + * {margin-top:30px;}`

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
h1.title {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: adding a margin-bottotm to the h1 element is very different than adding a margin-top to a child element

Comment: Looks the same to me.  With `margin-bottom` on `h1`: http://jsfiddle.net/L6cfuaqL/.  With `margin-top` on the adjacent siblings of `h1`: http://jsfiddle.net/77yksv5v/.

Comment: Yeah but... what if the h1 element is the only child? you will have an extra space and maybe it doesn't fit with the design...
then you have to set a new rule with h1.title:only-child to override the previous one

Comment: Contextually, why would the biggest heading element (`h1`) be the only child?  If that situation were to ever happen, then a developer has a bigger problem then finding the minimalist styles solution.  The very presence of `h1.title` implies that there is content that follows the `h1`.  Given the situation, the best solution is to give the heading the `margin-bottom`.  It is simpler and more efficient.